# jqGrid - loss of precision on grand total in summary footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I wonder why this Summary Footer's total was **sometimes** loss decimal precision.
Note: **sometimes** means there are times it is correct, and not correct, regardless of how much data displayed.

[image]

so here is my code:

```
jQuery("#clientSalesAnalysisReportTable").jqGrid({
    //url:'ClientSalesAnalysisReportGet',
    datatype: "xml",
    postData: {},
    colNames: ['Billing Status','Month-To-Date Totals'],
    colModel: [
        {name:'bill_stat',index:'bill_stat', width:'2px', sortable:false, title:true, align:"left", search:true, stype:'select', searchoptions:{value:':All;>=6:POSTED;<6:PENDING'}},
        {name:'month_to_date',index:'month_to_date', width:'2px', sortable:false, title:true, align:"right", search:false, formatter:'currency',formatoptions:{ thousandsSeparator:","}}
    ],
    pager: '#clientSalesAnalysisReportPager',
    rowNum: 10000,
    autowidth:true,
    shrikToFit:true,
    scroll:true,
    height:470,
    sortname: 'cust_num',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    hidegrid:false,
    footerrow : true,
    userDataOnFooter : true,
    gridComplete: function(data){
        var grid = jQuery('#clientSalesAnalysisReportTable');
        grid.jqGrid('footerData','set',{
            bill_stat: 'Total',
            month_to_date: parseFloat(grid.jqGrid('getCol','month_to_date',false,'sum')).toFixed(2),
            year_to_date: parseFloat(grid.jqGrid('getCol','years',false,'sum')).toFixed(2)
        });
    },
    loadComplete: function(data){ }
});
```

Comment: The picture which you posted don't contain any problem. So one can only guess what problem you could have. I recommend you to analyse the value returned by `getCol` in case when the problem ("lost" decimal precision) exists.